# How to use Pry within Factory Girl Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, pry

In order to debug a factory I've inserted `rescue binding.pry` at the end of a problematic line:

```
after_create do |my_object, proxy|
  my_object.foreign_key_id = proxy.generated_attribute rescue binding.pry
```

Unfortunately, inside the resulting `FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit` context I can't seem to access the context like I would in "normal" code (`` NameError: undefined local variable or method `proxy' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x0...> ``). **How do I inspect and manipulate `my_object` and `proxy` within the Pry session?**

The code is called as part of the background of a Cucumber feature:

```
Given the following my_objects exist:
| property |
| value    |
```

`factory_girl_rails` and `factory_girl/step_definitions.rb` are required by the support script.

Comment: I think that callback block takes only one argument. Anyway you could move `binding.pry` form the rescue block, put it above the second line and see what happen.

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly you're going to achieve?

Comment: @luacassus: The repo has an [example](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) with two arguments.

Comment: @luacassus: Putting `binding.pry` above the failing line makes no discernable difference - `my_object` still isn't available.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `Factory.create` instead `Factory.build` or other method?

Comment: It should be `create` - We're using the [Cucumber helpers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb#L113).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to allow attribute names to define attributes without having a block argument, factory_girl evaluates the definition block using `instance_eval` and undefines most private methods on `Object`, including `binding`. That means that when you call `binding.pry` above, you're not calling `pry` on the binding for that block; instead, you're defining a new attribute with a name of "binding" and invoking `pry` on the created attribute definition.

You can get around this by using `Kernel.binding.pry` instead.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This had been haunting me for a while now :)

Comment: Just in case ppl are wondering, it works with byebug as well.
`Kernel.binding.byebug`